# ansible task -easy_install with requirements.txt file

Tags: ansible

I want to run [easy_install](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/easy_install_module.html) task in order to install many modules in virtual environment.

Is there an option to install all modules in requirements.txt file? as I understand it accept only one module at a time.

Another option is to do it with `with_items` but how can I make Ansible 
iterate over both the name and the version of each module

```
- name: Install things 
  easy_install:
   name: pip
   state: latest
```

I want certain versions obviously...

I can not work with Pip task, only easy_install.
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the ansible version? It seems like you're using a slightly older version, referring to `with_items` - this is replaced by `loop` in recent versions.

Comment: version: ansible 2.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over file content:

```
- name: Installs Python libraries from requirements.txt
  easy_install:
    name: {{ item }}
    state: present
  with_lines: cat "/my_app/requirements.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop with dictionaries using `loop`. It doesn't look like the `easy_install` module handles versions with a module attribute, so you might have t pass the version on the `name` attribute.

```
- name: install things with easy_install
  easy_install:
    name: "{{ item.name }}=={{item.version}}"
    state: present
  loop:
    - { name: 'pip', version: '18.1' }
```